# Command for database migration in Yii 2.0

Tags: php, mysql, yii

While studying Yii 2.0, I've come across different ways people migrate their database. The first one, which I follow usually is from [yii 2's guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html).

Using this guide, I use commands such as **yii migrate/create migrationfile** and **yii migrate**

Normally inside my migration file **up()**, method I'd insert code like so:

```
$this->createTable('news', [
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'title' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'content' => Schema::TYPE_TEXT,
]);
```

However, I've also seen some tutorials such as [this one](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/490/creating-a-simple-crud-app-with-yii2-revised-12-20-2013/#hh8) which uses a slightly different command and code in the migration file. From the second tutorial, I've used *php yii migrate/create migrationfile*

While the syntax used in the migration file *up()* method was something like so:

```
return $this->createTable('posts', [
        'id' => 'INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT',
        'title' => 'VARCHAR(255)',
        'content' => 'TEXT',
```

Now, this has resulted in number of questions.
1. Is there are difference between **php yii** and **yii** command?
2. What's the difference between using **Schema::** vs not using it? Is it a better approach in migrating the database since it's what's written on Yii's guide to migrations or is it just a matter of preference which one to use?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Using `yii` and `php yii` is exactly the same. If you check out the `yii` file, you'll see this on the first line: `#!/usr/bin/env php`. This is called the "shebang" syntax, and instructs your shell to automatically execute the `yii` script using the `php` binary. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

2) The difference here is flexibility. If you use the `Schema::TYPE_PK` syntax, Yii will automatically determine the exact column type based on your database backend. For example, `Schema::TYPE_PK` would translate to `int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` in MySQL, but if you'd use Postgres as database, it would translate to `serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` instead. [1]

In practice it's unlikely to make a difference which method you use, because you're probably not going to switch to a different type of database halfway through your project and thus there's no need for your migration scripts to be database-agnostic. Based on your preferences, you could opt for the `Schema` syntax for the extra flexibility, or for the hardcoded syntax to make your migration definitions more clear to anyone reading them in the future.

[1] See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/pgsql/QueryBuilder.php#L21 and https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/mysql/QueryBuilder.php#L24